# Passing node object as parameter in graph query Py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have the following code in which I am obtaining a node. How can I pass it to graph.evaluate as a parameter. Is there a possible method to do so if this is incorrect ? Or some alternative method

```
user_node = selector.select("User", user_id=95)
lib_node = graph.evaluate("match {param}-[:LISTENS_TO]->(p) return p", param=dict(user_node))
```

the above throws value error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` method returns a selection of as many matches as it can find. This may or may not be a sequence of one but either way, you'll need to use the `.first()` method to grab the first (and probably only) one returned.

http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.selection.NodeSelection.first

Comment: can the node then be passed as parameter itself to graph.evaluate as above line 2

Comment: I am trying to pass the node object itself as a parameter and not just its property values

Comment: No, you cannot use graphy objects (nodes, rels or paths) as parameters.